# How to insert a textbox value inside a script variable using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Below is the code. 
**Goal:** Replace "amount" value with the value present in "re_valve" value on Clicking button with id="rp_button6".

> Extract This Value

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="re_valve">
```

> Initiating Button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" id="rp-button6">Pay Amount</button>
```

> Script Where Value Is To be Inserted

```
<script>
var options = {
    "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "amount": "2000", // 2000 paise = INR 20
    "name": "<?php echo $m9['fname']; ?> <?php echo $m9['lname']; ?>",
    "description": "Digital Server Renewal",
    "image": "http://www.digitalocean.com/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png",
    "handler": function (response){

       $("#payment_gateway_stargate_2").html(response.rarpay_payment_id);
    var rpid = response.rarpay_payment_id;
    window.location = '/receipt.php?billno=' + rpid;

    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": "<?php echo $m9['fname']; ?> <?php echo $m9['lname']; ?>",
        "email": "<?php echo $m9['email']; ?>",
        "contact": "<?php echo $m9['phone']; ?>"
    },
    "notes": {
        "shopping_id": "<?php echo encrypt_ssc($_SESSION['user_id'].'_'.rand(999,9999)); ?>"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
    }
};
var rp6 = new Rarpay(options);

document.getElementById('rp-button6').onclick = function(e){
    rp6.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the value from the input, then assign it to the `options` object.

Note that there is ZERO "defensive code" in this example. (meaning checking if the re_valve element exists before relying on getting it's value, checking if the `options` object exists before setting `options.amount`, etc.)

```
document.getElementById('rp-button6').onclick = function(e) {
    // get the value of the re_valve input
    var amount = document.getElementById('re_valve').value;
    // assign the value to the "amount" property of "options" object
    options.amount = amount;
    // note that the below would also work:
    // options['amount'] = amount;
    rp6.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: might be better to initialize the `rp6` object after extending options also since it's not known what `new Rarpay` does

Comment: Nope! Not working! Clicking on "rp-button6" should fetch the value from "re_valve" and send it as "amount" value under "options"

Comment: @ArijitAich - that's what this does.  Can you explain what is wrong with it? Or, if it DOES work, delete your comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('rp-button6').onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    options.value = document.getElementById('re_valve').value;
    rp6.open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will depend on what `Rarpay()` does with `options` - if it's still referencing the original then ;

```
document.getElementById('rp-button6').onclick = function(e){
    options.amount = document.getElementById('re_valve').value ;
    rp6.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

otherwise ( or in either case )

```
document.getElementById('rp-button6').onclick = function(e){
    options.amount = document.getElementById('re_valve').value ;
    rp6 = new Rarpay(options);
    rp6.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

(assuming creating a new `Rarpay` is ok)

Comment: try setting a break point at rp6.open and check what options.amount is before and after stepping over it.

Comment: Is your script before the html for the button and input ? - if so the elements won't be found / listeners attached - make sure the <script> etc is after the html - eg just before </body>